# Callback/Closure Issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, closures

Afternoon all,

I'm a really new NodeJS programmer (three weeks experience) and am really struggling with the below code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var async = require('async');
var async2 = require('async');
var async3 = require('async');

function updateJSONSubmission(submission, mainCallback) {

  async.each(submission.list, function(topItem, outerCallback) {

    console.log("Outer Loop ");

    async2.each(topItem.fields.formFields, function(midItem, midCallback) {

      console.log("Middle Loop " + midItem.fieldId.type);

      if (midItem.fieldId.type === "signature" || midItem.fieldId.type === "photograph") {

          async3.each(midItem.fieldValues, function(innerItem, innerCallback) {

              console.log("Inner Loop " + innerItem.contentType);

              if (innerItem.contentType === "base64") {
                console.log("Found result: " + innerItem.fileName);

                innerItem.base64Image = innerItem.fileName;

                innerCallback(null, innerItem);
              }

          }, function(err) {
              midCallback(null, midItem);
          });

      }

    }, function(err) {
        outerCallback(null, topItem);
    });



  }, function(err) {
      //all loops complete
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Done");
          mainCallback(null, submission);
        }
  });

}
```

Essentially I'm trying to loop through a number of JSON arrays. As I'm debugging I'm hitting a problem once the first async.each has completed - I would expect this to then enter the below code, but it isn't:

```
 function(err) {
      //all loops complete
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Done");
          mainCallback(null, submission);
        }
```

I'm sure I've just got some closure/callback incorrect but it's driving me mental trying to find it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your condition `if (midItem.fieldId.type === "signature" || midItem.fieldId.type === "photograph")` is false, `midCallback` is never called.

The same with `if (innerItem.contentType === "base64")`

---

Also, you don't need to require `async` module multiple times. Require it once, then simply use it.

```
const async = require('async');

async.each(obj, (data) => {
  async.parallel([]);
});
```